# Intermittent blank DataFrame with xbbg BDP calls

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I have an issue where occasionally blp.bdp() from **xbbg** returns an empty DataFrame, even though the security and the field data exists in Bloomberg. This seems to be an intermittent issue, as when I re-run the call for a particular bond the data arrives as expected.

For example:

```
from xbbg import blp

df = blp.bdp('FR0126461682 Govt',['AMT_OUTSTANDING','AMT_ISSUED'])
```

As I said, usually this works, but on sporadic occasions (and for a different security each time) the DataFrame comes back empty. The calls are part of a loop over 300+ bonds, so am I hitting some transaction limit somewhere?

Has anyone else experienced this?

Windows 10. Python 3.7. xbbg 0.7.5, blpapi 3.16.2

Comment: limit should be much higher than 300 data points

Comment: Haven't tried myself but try replacing the yellow-key 'Govt' with simply 'ISIN'. May not solve your issue but sometimes the yellow-key suffix is buggy for me. 'ISIN' is just a catch-all when using bonds (for both Corp and Govt).

Comment: this should be a timeout issue. try to load fewer bonds for each call, or use `timeout` for your calls: `blp.bdp(..., timeout=5000)` (5s for the server to respond)

Comment: @Alpha Thanks ... it never occurred to me that there is a timeout, but it makes sense. I’m working from home, so the internet could be slower than I am used to.